# How to merge create a column in R that only take one value based on update date

Tags: r

I am new R and have a matrix below:

earning

```
0  Name     usd/day  update_year  usd/day update_year
1  John     52.0     2011         NA       NA
2  Mary     44.0     2012         NA       NA
3  Nicole   44.5     2000 est.    49.2     2010 est.
4  Cynthia   38.1    2001 est.    44.0     2011
```

I wanted to clean up the data in R, to only have 3 columns - Name, usd/day and update_year and get something like this:

```
0  Name    usd/day  update_year
1  John    52.0     2011
2  Mary    44.0     2012
3  Nicole  49.2     2010
4  Cynthia 44.0     2011
```

How do I go about doing that in R please?

I don't want to manually combine them and the actual data is more than 100 rows.

Comment: For one thing, you have repeated column names in your data frame which will cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It seems that you want to extract the most recent date (i.e., year) and the highest value for USD. There's a couple of things you need to do.

First, only keep the year in `update_year`; it seems that you don't want ' est.' in your final table. We can do that using `gsub`.

```
df$update_year.x <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", df$update_year.x)
df$update_year.y <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", df$update_year.y)
```

Find the most recent year.

```
df$update_year <- apply(df[, c(4,6)], 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Find the highest USD value.

```
df$usd.day <- apply(df[, c(3,5)], 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Keep relevant columns.

```
df[, c("Name", "usd.day", "update_year")]

#     Name usd.day update_year
#1    John    52.0        2011
#2    Mary    44.0        2012
#3  Nicole    49.2        2010
#4 Cynthia    44.0        2011
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text="
X0  Name     usd/day.x  update_year.x  usd/day.y update_year.y
1  John     52.0     2011         NA       NA
2  Mary     44.0     2012         NA       NA
3  Nicole   44.5     '2000 est.'    49.2     '2010 est.'
4  Cynthia   38.1    '2001 est.'    44.0     2011", header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

As pointed out in the comments to your answer; there are duplicate column names and that's a problem. I solved that here by adding x/y at the end of the names.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I handle if the usd/day drops? I have a few records who earns less as of later update.

Comment: Do you want the value in the second usd/day column only if it's not NA, and the value from the first usd/day column otherwise? Then you could do this: ifelse(is.na(df[,6]), df[,4], df[,6]).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pmax` after replacing the values with `gsub`

```
update_year <- do.call(pmax, c(lapply(df[c(4,6)], function(x) 
                    as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", x))), list(na.rm=TRUE)))
`usd/day` <- do.call(pmax, c(df[c(3,5)], list(na.rm=TRUE)))   


cbind(df[1:2], `usd/day`, update_year)
#   0    Name   usd/day update_year
#1  1    John      52.0        2011
#2  2    Mary      44.0        2012
#3  3  Nicole      49.2        2010
#4  4 Cynthia      44.0        2011
```